# Scala implicit not found "not enough arguments"

Tags: scala, implicits

In this simple code i have a method `buildResponse` which takes a type parameter T which must be a subtype of `Response`.

Now the compiler tells me it does not find an implicit value when i call `new ResponseBuilder().build\[T]()` inside alltough i have defined an implicit for class Response in the Builder companion object.

I thought due T must be a subtype of `Response` it will take the implicit value for `Builder[Response]`. If T would be something else then `Response` i would have excpected this error.

So whats the right way to get this done ?

```
import scala.util.Try;

object Main extends App {



  case class Response(val v:String){

  }

  sealed trait Builder[T] {
    def build(): Try[T]
  }

  object Builder {
    implicit val BuilderResponse = new Builder[Response] {
      def build(): Try[Response] = {
        Try {
          Response("Hello")
        }
      }
    }

    implicit val BuilderInt = new Builder[Int] {
      def build(): Try[Int] = {
        Try {
          1
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class ResponseBuilder
  {
    def build[T:Builder]() : Try[T] = {
       implicitly [Builder[T]].build()
    }
  }

  // works fine
  //new ResponseBuilder().build[Response]();


  //not enough arguments for method build: (implicit evidence$1: Main.Builder[T])scala.util.Try[T]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
  def buildResponse[T <: Response ]() : Try[T] = {
    new ResponseBuilder().build[T]();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that you need an implicit value of type `Builder[Response]` but of type `Builder[T]`. The implicit value `BuilderResponse: Builder[Response]` cannot be used here because `T` can be any subtype of `Response`.

You can make the code compiling by either adding a `Builder` context bound to your method `buildResponse`

```
def buildResponse[T <: Response: Builder]() : Try[T] = {
  new ResponseBuilder().build[T]();
}
```

Or by defining an implicit method `createBuilder[T <: Response]: Builder[T]` in the `Builder` companion object which generates the `Builder` objects somehow.

```
implicit def createBuilder[T <: Response]: Builder[T] = ...
```